# How do you migrate django auth from mongo to SQL? (ManyRelatedManger on Mongo)

Tags: django, mongodb

I have multiple databases.  The legacy Mongo db, 'mongo' and the new PostgreSQL db I am migrating to, 'sql'.  I am trying to move all of the users and their permissions over.

In the code I have already moved the Permissions over from 'mongo' to 'sql'.

```
users = User.objects.using('mongo').all().values('username')
for user in users:
    u = User.objects.db_manager('sql').create_user(user.username, user.email, user.password)
    # Where the ManyRelatedManager trouble begins
    # This error is "'dict' object has no attribute 'user_permissions'"
    u.user_permissions.add(user.user_permissions)
    # This error is "This query is not supported by the database." on the .all()
    old_permissions = user.user_permissions.all()
    for p in old_permissions:
         new_permission = Permission.objects.using('sql').get(name=p.name)
         u.user_permissions.add(new_permission)
         u.save()
```

Since Mongo doesn't like joins how can I access the Permission objects for a user?

Comment: My workaround was to give all Permssions to users who are superusers.  I never correctly solved how I can access the Permission objects for a user using mongo.  (Iterate over the documents and populate in SQL-land was too vague to be a solution.)

Answer (score 1):

So if I look in my django project (sqlite3) there are 7 tables that are created when you sync the auth app. I would take a look at how each is created in a standard django app

```
auth_group         
auth_group_permissions
auth_message
auth_permission
auth_user
auth_user_groups
auth_user_user_permissions
```

If I display the schema for them, it looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "auth_group" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(80) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
CREATE TABLE "auth_group_permissions" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "group_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "permission_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "auth_permission" ("id"),
    UNIQUE ("group_id", "permission_id")
);
CREATE TABLE "auth_message" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "user_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id"),
    "message" text NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE "auth_permission" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    "content_type_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "codename" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE ("content_type_id", "codename")
);
CREATE TABLE "auth_user" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "username" varchar(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "first_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "last_name" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    "email" varchar(75) NOT NULL,
    "password" varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    "is_staff" bool NOT NULL,
    "is_active" bool NOT NULL,
    "is_superuser" bool NOT NULL,
    "last_login" datetime NOT NULL,
    "date_joined" datetime NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE "auth_user_groups" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "user_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "group_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "auth_group" ("id"),
    UNIQUE ("user_id", "group_id")
);
CREATE TABLE "auth_user_user_permissions" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "user_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "permission_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "auth_permission" ("id"),
    UNIQUE ("user_id", "permission_id")
);
```

Use syncdb to create those tables in your new DB after enabling the auth app and then iterate over the documents in the mongo version. For each document, populate the appropriate tables in SQL-land.